# spring securtity rest api not secured with keycloak

Tags: spring, keycloak

I'm have integrated the keycloak with legacy spring app. I have addedd the keycloak spring security adapter to my pom.xml file and added the security configuration. After everything done I'm able to access the rest api without token. How i solve this problem?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    /**
     * Registers the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider with the authentication manager.
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    /**
     * Defines the session authentication strategy.
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/school-admin*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

**keycloak.json**

```
{
  "realm": "appscook",
  "bearer-only": true,
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "ssd-backend"
}
```

**Api**

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/hello",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
     public String getStandards(){
        return "hello";
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try, following configure function.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
}
```

Also you can use, @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')") annotation on controller's function, with following Spring configuration;

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

Answer (score 0):

"/hello" does not match ""/school-admin*" specified in your config method.

Comment: "/hello" is inside of class level request mapping "/school-admin*"

Comment: And did you try with adding a slash before the * "/school-admin/*"